# How to apply CSS using jquery after page refresh ( Assing the CSS before refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

on my Master page I am applying the CSS to selected link in the accordion panel. But once I click the button page getting refreshed and I am loosing my CSS. is there anyway we can still keep the class applied on the selected link ( or Highlight the selected link) after the page refresh?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#accordian li').click(function () {
                var href = $(this).addClass("active1").children("a").attr("href");
            });
});
```

Comment: You could change just parts of the page or use localStorage.

Comment: I need to achieve this functionality in asp.net mvc master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var key = 'clickedHref';
      $("#clearButton").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem(key, null);
      });

      $('#accordian li').click(function() {
    $("#accordian li").removeClass("active1");
        var href = $(this).addClass("active1").children("a").attr("href");
        localStorage.setItem(key, href);
      });

      var clickedHref = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (clickedHref !== null) {
        var a = $('#accordian li a[href="' + clickedHref + '"]');
        if (a.length) {
          a.trigger("click");
        }
      }
    });
```

css:

```
.active1 a{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

html:

```
<ul id="accordian">
    <li>
        <a href="?a=1">a1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?a=2">a2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<button id='clearButton'>clear</button>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGVjjP

Comment: Thank you. I am getting undefined after the page refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Using "preventDefault()" not solve your case?

```
$('#accordian li').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var href = $(this).addClass("active1").children("a").attr("href");
});
```